# Magento 2 : Steps to initiate return in Magento ver. 2.4.1

Tags: magento2

How to initiate return in Magento ver. 2.4.1 ?

Comment: What is your current magento version?

Comment: Magento 2.4 (Enterprise)

Comment: @devhs please go through official documentation https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/returns.html